# What is the difference between net4 and net40 folders in my nuget package?

Tags: c#, sqlite, nuget

I have installed a nuget package. [SQLite.Net-PCL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net-PCL/) and in the package folder I can see two folders `net4` and `net40` shown below:

[image]

These folders contain different `dlls` My project is referencing the dll in the `net40` folder but I would like it to reference the `net4` dll.

Whats the difference between these two folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [NuGet's enforced conventions](https://docs.nuget.org/create/enforced-package-conventions), net4 is probably not valid. net40 or 40 are accepted values. Looking at the NuGet frameworks [code](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/search?l=csharp&q=net40&utf8=%E2%9C%93), I dont see a place where this is valid. Maybe, this was a mistake from the package authors side.

You are referencing the right assembly based on NuGet's conventions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will follow this up with the package owner

Comment: This was infact confirmed as a bug by the package owner